# MDX - Get the last value of a parent group on rows

Tags: ssas, mdx, tail

I have a dataset that should output the last segment of each quarter (2015 Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4). With the latest segment I mean the last value of the segment attribute from the first week in its respective quarter until the selected date as a parameter.

The query below is outputting

- 2015 Q1 - C
- 2015 Q2 - /

The problem is that from 2015 W1 - 2015 W14 the segment is always C. After W14 the segment becomes "/". It thus look to me that the query is not taking into account the YTD function.

```
SET [All calendars] AS
    [Date invoice].[Bonus calendar - Quarter].[Bonus Quarter].ALLMEMBERS


SET [Stratum history] AS
    Generate(
        {[All calendars]} AS s
        ,s.Current
            *HEAD(
                NonEmpty
                (
                 [Stratum history].[Stratum].[Stratum]
                ,[Stratum sales average]
                )
            ,1
            )
    )
```

The where clause:

```
WHERE
//Only calculate for the current bonus year until the current week
StrToMember("[Date invoice].[Bonus year].&[" + CStr(StrToMember(@PAR_Date).Parent.MemberValue) + "]")
*Ytd(StrToMember(@PAR_Date))
*StrToMember(@POS_ID)
```

If I change the All calendars set to [Date invoice].[Bonus calendar - Quarte].[Bonus week of quarter].ALLMEMBERS then I get the full set

2015 W1 - C
...
2015 W14 - C

The query then stops at 2015 W14 as specified in my where clause! But I only want to show the quarter level on my rows.

Any advise?

Comment: W1 corresponds to Q1 and W14 corresponds to Q2, right? Or how is it?

Comment: The `WHERE` clause looks fine to me.

Comment: Can you give any sample value of `@PAR_Date` and also tells us how your `[Bonus year]` hierarchy looks like?

Answer (score 0):

How about you modify the `NonEmpty` clause of the second set a bit like below:

```
SET [Stratum history] AS
    Generate(
        {[All calendars]} AS s
        ,s.Current
            *HEAD(
                NonEmpty
                (
                 [Stratum history].[Stratum].[Stratum].MEMBERS
                ,([Stratum sales average], s.Current)
                )
            ,1
            )
    )
```